# How to use TypeScript based libraries from node_modules into AngularJs-v1.2.20

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, splunk, open-telemetry

I am trying to import `trace` from `@opentelemetry/api` into AngularJs controller but the library is TypeScript based so not able to import it into code.

For example, if I have to use `validator` library (`npm i validator`) then I can import it using the following code snippent:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  validator.isemail('foo@bar.com');
</script>
```

**How can I use `trace` from `@opentelemetry/api` in AngularJs-v1.2.20 controller?**

Comment: I don't think you can import Typescript into Javascript. Typescript is a superset, meaning you can import JS into TS but not the opposite. You need to fully work in TS for that.

Comment: BTW Angularjs 1.2 has been released somewhere around 2013 or 2014, I sure hope you have a good reason to still use it :) Old project maintenance, I assume?